# Когда срабатывает changedUpdate()?

Tags: java

Никак не могу понять, когда срабатывает метод `changedUpdate()` интерфейса `DocumentListener`. Можно объяснение и пример, когда он будет срабатывать? Документация не дала понятного ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот метод вызывается, когда изменены атрибуты документа(шрифт, размер и т.д.), но не текст. Например, в этом примере:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;

public class JTextTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame jf = new JFrame("JTextTest");
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      final JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Some text...");

    DocumentListener dl = new DocumentListener() {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Was insert...");
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Was remove...");
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Was change...");
        }
    };
    jtf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dl);


    jf.add(jtf);
    jf.setSize(150, 100);
    jf.setVisible(true);

  }
 }
```

Если я изменю шрифт в textField, этот метод вызовется.
P.S. Код не мой http://javatalks.ru/topics/251?page=1#650
Также можно посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757555/java-documentlistener.
P.P.S. Надеюсь, можно кидать ссылки на внешние ресурсы.